# How to set up a Web Map Service with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server

I am very new to QGIS environment.I wanted to work with creating Web Map Service using QGIS server.

Is it possible to create Web Map Service in QGIS server?

Comment: Hi, do you want to run it on windows or linux?

Comment: i wanted to work with windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official page for QGIS server is this [one.](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial)
For windows you could take a look [here.](http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/)
For ubuntu [here](http://www.aboutgis.ro/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/qgis_desk_web_server_client_tutorial.pdf) .
You could also download OSGeo live iso or vm and have a quick look [on how it is done](http://live.osgeo.org/en/overview/qgis_mapserver_overview.html) in their setup.

You publish your QGIS Desktop projects into QGIS server which outputs WMS or WFS.

Comment: thnks a lot....

Comment: You might need the 32 bit Windows OSGEO4W version to get it running.